# symfony2 use global validator service in my own service

Tags: service, symfony-2.4

I am new in symfony, and I see in the documents, that I can get and use validator service in the controller like:

```
$this->get('validator');
```

what is the  right\easy way to get the validator service in my own service class that i wrote

thank you

Comment: inject it to the service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inject it into the service like this

```
your.service:
    class: Path\To\Your\Service
    arguments: [@validator]
```